# Wordpress, Highlight text on mouse hover

Tags: wordpress, text, plugins, highlight, effect

Hi everyone is it possible in wordpress to create a similar effect when you go over a text with the mouse pointer?

see the example image

[image]

thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really related to Wordpress, more a CSS(/JS?) question.

A simple way to achieve it would be to add a specific class to the container of the text you want to have the effect, then handle the effect using CSS only.

Here is an exemple using a link but it should be applicable to any kind of text :
https://codyhouse.co/ds/components/app/text-background-effects

Here is as sample code :

```
.text-bg-fx {
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            padding: 3px;
            background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #a7c7dc 0%,#85b2d3 100%); 
            background-size: 0% 100%;
            will-change: background-size;
            transition: background-size .3s ease-in-out;
        }

        .text-bg-fx:hover {
            background-size: 100% 100%
        }
```

Comment: Please copy the CSS content you wanted to refer to inside your answer. Link-only answers may easily get useless if the link gets broken, and they're also not allowed on StackOverflow.